# Cannot catch HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, try-catch

I am failing to incorporate `try & except` functionality into my loop. Here is the code if you want to reproduce the error:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request
from urllib.error import HTTPError

start = datetime.datetime.strptime("19-09-2016", "%d-%m-%Y")
end = datetime.datetime.strptime("31-12-2017", "%d-%m-%Y")
date_generated = [start + datetime.timedelta(days = x) for x in range(0, (end - start).days)]

dates_list = []
for date in date_generated:
    txt = str(str(date.day) + '.' + str(date.month) + '.' + str(date.year))
    dates_list.append(txt)

ndf = pd.DataFrame()  # create empty ndf
for i in range(0, len(dates_list)):
    allURL = 'https://www.uzse.uz/trade_results?date=' + dates_list[i] + '&locale=en&mkt_id=ALL&page=%d'

    for k in range(1, 100):
        url = allURL % k

        errors = []
        try:
            pd.read_html(url)[0].empty
        except HTTPError:
            errors.append(url)

        if pd.read_html(url)[0].empty:
            break
        else:
            chunk = pd.read_html(url)[0]
            chunk['Date'] = dates_list[i] # Date is positioned at last position, let's fix that
            cols = chunk.columns.tolist() # get a list of all the columns
            cols = cols[-1:] + cols[:-1] # rearrange the columns, move the last element (Date) to the first position
            chunk = chunk[cols] # reorder the dataframe
            ndf = pd.concat([ndf, chunk])

print(ndf)
```

I tried to modify `try & except` in many ways. But I cannot get it working ... I also want to store all those broken URLs for further manual checks. The above code reports this:

```
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-31cafbad5945> in <module>()
     26             errors.append(url)
     27 
---> 28         if pd.read_html(url)[0].empty:
     29             break
     30         else:

 346     # this version of raise is a syntax error in Python 3

HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

Comment: Why are you evaluating `pd.read_html(url)[0].empty` twice?

Comment: I feel like my code is failing there as shown in the `line 28`. That is why I am trying to skip it if there is an error. I think I have tried to change it to something like `try: url`, but it still did not work ...

Comment: That didn't answer my question.

Comment: first to check if the URL is working, the second is to check if the table is empty. does this answer your question?

Comment: The concept behind exception handling is to handle the problem when it happens, not to check for problems before. The second request is not guaranteed to have the same result as the first.

Answer (score 2):

The error is triggert because of the 2nd `pd.read_html(url)` in the line `if pd.read_html(url)[0].empty:`. The first `HTTPError` is handled by the `try/except`, the second time you are calling the same URL that failed before without a safeguard.

Secondly because of the `break` `errors` will only have 1 entry. I'm not sure of you want to save all failed ULRs or just the ones in the loop.

Give this a try.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from urllib.error import HTTPError

start = datetime.datetime.strptime("19-09-2016", "%d-%m-%Y")
end = datetime.datetime.strptime("31-12-2017", "%d-%m-%Y")
date_generated = [start + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (end - start).days)]

dates_list = []
for date in date_generated:
    txt = str(str(date.day) + '.' + str(date.month) + '.' + str(date.year))
    dates_list.append(txt)

ndf = pd.DataFrame()  # create empty ndf
for i in range(0, len(dates_list)):
    allURL = 'https://www.uzse.uz/trade1_results?date=' + dates_list[i] + '&locale=en&mkt_id=ALL&page=%d'
    errors = []

    for k in range(1, 100):
        url = allURL % k
        try:
            chunk = pd.read_html(url)[0]
            chunk['Date'] = dates_list[i]  # Date is positioned at last position, let's fix that
            cols = chunk.columns.tolist()  # get a list of all the columns
            cols = cols[-1:] + cols[:-1]  # rearrange the columns, move the last element (Date) to the first position
            chunk = chunk[cols]  # reorder the dataframe
            ndf = pd.concat([ndf, chunk])
        except HTTPError:
            errors.append(url)

    print(errors)
print(ndf)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking a look into this. Yeah, I was incorrectly located the `try & except` in the code. However, your version does not iterate through pages >10, which I really need. Also, I need all the URLs that do not work stored in `errors`.

Comment: @AK88 - I modfied the `for k in range(1, 10)` to test and forgot to change it back to 100. Changed the code.